# No content provider while reading google account photo

Tags: android, google-signin

I have an application with google sign in. I retrieve profile photo uri and try to save it in my external storage. When I do that, occurs *java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider*
Here is my permissions in AndroidManifest:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
```

Retrieve user info:

```
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
        String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
        Uri personPhotoURL = acct.getPhotoUrl();

        User user = new User();
        user.setName(personName);
        user.setEmail(personEmail);
        copyUserPhoto(personPhotoURL, user);
```

Function to save image:

```
  private void copyUserPhoto(Uri personPhotoURL, User user){
    File file = new UserDAO(getApplicationContext()).getPhotoFile(user);
    if(file.exists()) file.delete();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try{
        inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(personPhotoURL);
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int b = 0;
        while((b = inputStream.read())!=-1) 
            outputStream.write((byte)b);           

    } catch (Exception e){

    } finally {
        try{
            if(inputStream!= null)
                inputStream.close();
            if(outputStream!=null)
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e){

        }
    }
}
```

I've read a lot of info, but can't find decision.

Comment: What is the value of file.getAbsolutePath()?

Comment: Why dont you have have the normal code in that catchblock? Place a toast in it too to display e.getMessage().

Comment: What are the values of personPhotoURL.toString() and personPhotoURL.getPath()?

Comment: You should not try to vonvert a Uri to a File.